# C# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel exception when communicating with PHP scripts

Tags: c#, php, json, ssl

There's a random issue while my application communicates with a PHP script. It raises an exception, stating the following:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

The SSL on our server is working correctly, and this issue happens rarely, but it's still something I want to get to the bottom of.

```
var jsonParameters = new
{
    Data1 = value1,
    Data2 = value2
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonParameters);
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.example.com/phpscript.php?random=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks) as HttpWebRequest;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; //added this lately, but it didn't help
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
request.Timeout = 10000;
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(json);
}
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

string jsonresponse = "";

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        jsonresponse += reader.ReadLine();
    }
}

ResponseObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(jsonresponse);
```

I am basically sending a short JSON to the script, which does a database lookup, and responds with a specific JSON back.

Am I missing a setting on the **HttpWebRequest** object, that makes it raise this exception?

Or could it be, that there's something wrong with the SSL, and it doesn't respond always the same way?

Comment: This happened to me when I got https ssl sertificates setup wrong.

Comment: @Sv Sv Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I just did not create a ssl sertificate, so it failed to connect. This error happens from time to time anyway. Just retry an it will go away.

Answer (score 1):

The code example below enables all available protocols and ignores certificate errors. It's just for test. Care about ignoring certificate errors in production.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Comment: Ok, I enabled all the available protocols, and now I'm waiting for it to fail again. Problem is, it doesn't happen all the time, it just happens 1 out of 1000s of requests. I would not want to ignore certificate errors, tho.

Comment: @Laureant In this case I think it's server or connection issue

Comment: @openwix I ran an SSL check on the server, and it turned out to be OK. By server or connection issue you mean, that the certificate is not correctly sent to the client, so it's not recognized of being a trusted entity?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there may be some third party services which are accessed while handshaking: CA, CRL, OCSP checks and so on